# Why does my machine not boot?

Tags: linux, boot

*I think this is a HW issue so maybe I'm in the wrong place, please redirect me in that case.*

## History

I have a Lenovo 9142 that has been installed with Ubuntu and running as a developer machine for maybe 4-5 years. Then there was a disk failure so a new computer was bought. The old one was put aside for a month and then an old workstation that only serves a scanner broke so I figured I put a new disk in the Lenovo and extend its life some years.

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 again and everything worked fine until I started rebooting the thing.

## The error

This will describe the procedure to reproduce the problem (most of the times, but not always I think).

1. When I put the cord in the computer to give it power the fan will spin up for fraction of a second and then stop. The computer is now halted (this is normal behavior as far as I understand).
2. I now press the power button and the computer boots as expected.
3. Login and reboot (`sudo reboot` or `sudo shutdown -h now` will give the same result). It does not matter if I do this immediately or work for a while before rebooting.
4. The computer shutdown nicely and stop (like it's halted) but will not boot again.
5. **And now for the big issue:** Pressing the power button does nothing! No fan, no sound, not blinking, nothing! If I remove the powercord one or many timed does not change anything. It will not respond! The only way to get it to boot again is to remove the powercord for some minutes (5 works) and let it *rest*. When I now plug it in again I'm back at step 1.

Anyone with an idea about what this could be? Should I jut replace the computer or is there something that could be done to solve this?

Comment: I would think its a power HW problem any issue by motherboard should result in beeps. My guess would be the PSU, just try another one and see if the problem sticks.

Comment: IF you have to replace the PSU, get a new computer. I had that quite some times in my career and every time after that the machine started to fail component by component over some weeks. 4-5 years is old enough that a replacement is warranted anyway.

Comment: I'm all for a move, Should it be done my me by closing tis and posting again on SU or is  there some Move function and right to automate that?